# Cassandra Crashes on Start Up Mac

Tags: cassandra

When I try to start cassandra on Mac OSX Mavericks, it would open up but would give me this error.

```
grep: 4/bin/../conf/jvm.options: No such file or directory
```

What could have caused this?

In advance thanks!

Comment: How did you install C*? Is this CCM?

Comment: I had installed it off of planet cassandra and no I don't believe it's ccm

Comment: Is it better to use CCM? I just downloaded mirror http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/cassandra/3.7/apache-cassandra-3.7-bin.tar.gz, unzipped it, had updated java to the latest version.  When I clicked on /bin/cassandra it gives me above noted error and logout.... Do I need to change conf file? or just better to proceed with CCM?

Comment: You don't have to use CCM, I just thought it was attempting to use a numbered node subdirectory or something. 

I'm not sure where that error is coming from, i tried that download and it seems to be ok on my machine. Do you get any other messages? Have you tried just running from the cli?